# How to play hosted video on an image with Arkit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I can play the video with no issue when the video is locally stored but now I want to play a video that has been hosted on my google drive.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        if let trackedImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "TestImages", bundle: Bundle.main){
            configuration.trackingImages = trackedImages

            configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1
        }

        // Run the view's session
        ARView.session.run(configuration)
    }
```

Here is my function where the video is rendered onto the image:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        let node = SCNNode()

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor{

            let videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "Test.mp4")

            videoNode.play()

            let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1080, height:720 ))

            videoScene.addChild(videoNode)

            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

            videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width/2, y: videoScene.size.height/2)

            videoNode.yScale = -1.0

            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

            node.addChildNode(planeNode)


        }

        return node
    }
```

I am new to ARKIT so I am only learning the basic functions and enjoying working with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks just fine. Only thing that you need to change is the line that you've defined the `videoNode`

Example:

`let videoNode = SKVideoNode(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"))`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much! is there a way to do this using YouTube videos?

Comment: Can i detect  dynamic image which came from API  then video play?

Comment: Can i detect  dynamic image which came from API  then video play? instead of tracking through Assets?